# How to display a list in django tables 2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a list containing some objects that i want to display in django tables 2 but as a result i got the `-` in all the columns.
My list is like this format `[[<Person>],[<Person>]]`

Reading the documentation I've found that this format works :

```
data = [
    {"name": "Bradley"},
    {"name": "Stevie"},
]
```

How can I get a format like this knowing that my data is dynamic?

**Update :**
I tried this :

```
for x in person_list:
        for y in x:
            data=[ 
                   {"firstname": y.firstname},
                   {"surname":y.surname},
                   ]
```

The problem is now it displays every field in a row, I mean first name in row and surname in another one. How to append to the same `data` ?

Comment: Your list `[[<Person>],[<Person>]]`, is actually a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution to this inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492656/create-list-of-dictionary-python) :

```
d={}
    dlist=[]
    for x in person_list:
        for y in x:
            d['firstname']=y.firstname
            d['lastname']=y.lastname
            dlist.append(d)
```

And it works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Try to produce your data table manually
I suppose person has first_name field

```
data=[{"name": x.first_name} for x in persons_list]
```