# Unexpected result when generating a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to generate a list of dicts by two layer loop. At the outer loop, the generated dict will be appended into the list. But the output is not expected as below:

```
inf = []
infdic = {}
keys = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']

for c1 in range(2):
    for c2 in range(5):
        value = c1*10+c2
        key = keys[c2]
        infdic[key] = value
    inf.append(infdic)
    print c1, inf
```

The result of above code is:

```
0 [{'t4': 3, 't5': 4, 't2': 1, 't3': 2, 't1': 0}]
1 [{'t4': 13, 't5': 14, 't2': 11, 't3': 12, 't1': 10}, {'t4': 13, 't5': 14, 't2': 11, 't3': 12, 't1': 10}]
```

But what I want should be：

```
0 [{'t4': 3, 't5': 4, 't2': 1, 't3': 2, 't1': 0}]
1 [{'t4': 3, 't5': 4, 't2': 1, 't3': 2, 't1': 0}, {'t4': 13, 't5': 14, 't2': 11, 't3': 12, 't1': 10}]
```

It looks like the list `inf` is pointed to `infdic`, and it always changes as it does.
I am a little confused about how could this happen and how to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a list of dictionaries results in a list of copies of the same dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492656/creating-a-list-of-dictionaries-results-in-a-list-of-copies-of-the-same-dictiona)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks list "inf" is pointed to "infdic", and it always changes as
>   it does.

Yep, that's **exactly** what your code says to do, and, lo and behold, Python does precisely what you tell it to!-)

Fix: make a new `infdic` each time around:

```
for c1 in range(2):
    infdic = {}
    for c2 in range(5):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not resetting `infdic` in your outermost loop.

You loop through `c1` and you set up `infdic` as expected. But then you loop through `c2` and overwrite the contents of infidc! It can be fixed by setting `infdic = {}` in your outermost loop:

> ```
> inf = []
> keys = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']
>
> for c1 in range(2):
>     infdic = {}
>     for c2 in range(5):
>         value = c1*10+c2
>         key = keys[c2]
>         infdic[key] = value
>     inf.append(infdic)
>     print c1, inf
> ```

Also, regarding your observation:

> It looks list "inf" is pointed to "infdic", and it always changes as it does.

Yes, that's right. When you write `inf.append(infdic)` you are appending a **pointer** to `infdic` to the list `inf`. You're not copying a static version of the list (though you could using `copy.deepcopy`). I suggest you read up on how Python uses pointers, and shallow/deep copying.