# Pandas groupby is giving "keyError", even when the key exists

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, keyerror

I am new to Python, and for one of my project, I need to convert csv to nested Json. Searching on net, I found `pandas` are helpful in this case.
I followed the appraoch given in [Convert CSV Data to Nested JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095528/convert-csv-data-to-nested-json-in-python) 
But I am getting a keyError exception `KeyError: 'state'`

```
df info
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 3 columns):
country    4 non-null object
 state     4 non-null object
 city      4 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvToJson.py", line 31, in <module>
    grouped = df.groupby(['country', 'state'])
  File "/home/simarpreet/Envs/j/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 7632, in groupby
    observed=observed, **kwargs)
  File "/home/simarpreet/Envs/j/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 2110, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "/home/simarpreet/Envs/j/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 360, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)
  File "/home/simarpreet/Envs/j/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py", line 578, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'state'
```

Input csv:

```
country, state, city
India, Delhi, Tilak nagar
India, Mumbai, Bandra
Australia, Queensland, Gold Coast
US, California, Los Angeles
```

My Code:

```
csvFilePath = "/home/simarpreet/sampleCsv.csv"
jsonFilePath = "/home/simarpreet/sampleJson.json"
jsonFile = open(jsonFilePath, 'w')

df = pd.read_csv(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8-sig')
print("df info")
print(df.info())
finalList = []

grouped = df.groupby(['country', 'state'])
for key, value in grouped:
    dictionary = {}

    j = grouped.get_group(key).reset_index(drop=True)
    dictionary['country'] = j.at[0, 'country']
    dictionary['state'] = j.at[0, 'state']

    dictList = []
    anotherDict = {}
    for i in j.index:

        anotherDict['city'] = j.at[i, 'city']

        dictList.append(anotherDict)

    dictionary['children'] = dictList

    finalList.append(dictionary)

json.dumps(finalList)
```

Comment: check for whitespace around dataframe column headers after read_csv.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with your csv file, there are leading whistespaces in column names, because of which the key error is coming.

As pointed out by @cs95 you can do

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Or you can use read_csv to handle spaces:

`pd.read_csv(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8-sig', sep='\s*,\s*', engine='python')`

PS : Bad way to deal with it :

```
grouped = df.groupby(['country', ' state'])
```

Comment: @cs95 my bad, thanks for pointing out. Can I use your advice to improve the answer for others? Both of the ways you pointed out, looks really clean to deal with whitespaces in column names.

Comment: YES, please do so. And make sure your answers are solutions, not hacks ;)