# How to create a Dicts From a List of Dicts which the Keys are retracted from Dict Keys inside the list while keeping different values

Tags: python

I have this list here:

```
mechs= [
        {
            'type_code': 'GAT',
            'name': 'STRIKE',
            'unit_price': 3500,
            'minimum_kilo': 500,
        },
        {
            'type_code': 'GAT',
            'name': 'BLITZ',
            'unit_price': 2500,
            'minimum_kilo': 520,
        },
        {
            'type_code': 'ZGMF',
            'name': 'LEGEND',
            'unit_price': 4500,
            'minimum_kilo': 550,
        },
    ]
```

Then I wanted the output to be like:

```
mechas=
{'GAT': {
[
{'type_code': 'GAT',
  'name': 'STRIKE',
  'unit_price': 3500,
  'minimum_kilo': 500},
{'type_code': 'GAT',
  'name': 'BLITZ',
  'unit_price': 2500,
  'minimum_kilo': 520}
]
}

#continue to next dict...
```

How do I get the 'GAT' dict to put the next value(dict) to the dict instead of reassigning them?

Here is what I have used:

```
mechas={}
for i in mechs:
    mechas[i['type_code']]=i
```

And the output is like this:

```
{'GAT': {'type_code': 'GAT',
  'name': 'BLITZ',
  'unit_price': 2500,
  'minimum_kilo': 520},
 'ZGMF': {'type_code': 'ZGMF',
  'name': 'LEGEND',
  'unit_price': 4500,
  'minimum_kilo': 550}}
```

This output does not include the previous value (code GAT name STRIKE), so how do I keep it instead of reassigning a new value?

I actually tried list(), append(), etc. but I think it's too long to put it here and the result still does not satisfy me.

Comment: The output you want isn't valid, you can't put a list in a set. Do you want a dictionary whose values are _lists_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah i see, yes i want a dictionary that values are set, and can contain thoose mechs values with same code but different names.

Comment: You can't put dictionaries in a set either. The values must be hashable and that generally means immutable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe does that mean I can only put 1 dict on the key? do I need to create a new different key to assign the unlisted dict?

Comment: No, it just means you can't use a set, because the values you want to store are dictionaries, which are mutable. There are other containers (a list, as I've already suggested, for example).

Comment: okay, so i need to filter by those type_code that have the same that have a code, append the dict to a list for each code, and put it into dict, is that true?

Comment: Yes, sort of. And before you append to the list, first check if the list exists for that key, or use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). If you **show your code** in a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then you might get answers for how to solve this.

Comment: @dgrszombie315 , You wont be able to add data type in a set (_Which is immutable meaning values cant be changed_) which are mutable for example list, dictionary. You can add tuple or sets inside of sets as they are immutable.

Comment: @dgrszombie315 , i have posted an answer which i think would work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a={}
for i in mechs:
    type_code=i.get('type_code')
    if type_code not in a.keys():
        a[type_code]=i
    else:
        c=[a.get(type_code),i]
        a[type_code]=c
```

How does the above code works?, well here's the explanation:

- Just checked if a key of `type_code` is available in the `dict` or not.
- If its not available, then created a new key `type_code` and its value as the index we were reading.
- If its available, then took all the values to the corresponding `type_code` and added them into list, and also added the index value to the list. Then changed the previous value of `type_code` with the newly created list.

Comment: Thank You, this worked perfectly, didn't come in my mind i could use keys() and get()

Comment: @dgrszombie315 , glad it helped you. You can press the tick button beside my answer also.

Comment: anyway, i tried this but, i created the GAT type code have  3 code, and ZGMF 3 too, 

i run again the code and it created a list inside a list, followed by a dictionary, i tried to configure around the i  and a.get(type_code) but still didnt work.

i also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492656/creating-a-list-of-dictionaries-results-in-a-list-of-copies-of-the-same-dictiona

But i cant still figure it out to create just a list with a dictionaries only

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
mechas={}
for i in mechs:
  if i['type_code'] not in mechas:
    mechas[i['type_code']]=[]
  mechas[i['type_code']].append(i)
```

Comment: Does not work on me but thanks

Comment: This won't work at all, it's not syntactically or semantically valid.