# Creating a list of dictonary items

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary `{"123":"Pass","987":"Fail","765":"Pass"}`  that is being populated and returned from a function (shown below). I need to make this a list of dictionaries like `[{Id:"123", value:"Pass"},{Id:"987", value:"Fail"}, {Id:"765", value:"Pass"}]`. I'm new to python and I was wondering if there is a way that I could either create a list of dictionaries (instead of creating a dictionary) before returning it?

Function I'm using:

```
nodes = {}
def populateItems(response):
    for res in response:
        if response["Status"] == "Pass":
            nodes[response["key"]]=response["Status"]
    return nodes
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492656/creating-a-list-of-dictionaries-results-in-a-list-of-copies-of-the-same-dictiona

Comment: So function `populateItems` is called mulitple times to populate `nodes`, so I think I need to find a way to populate a list which has a template of `{id: <someValue>, key:<someValue>}`. I'm not sure how I could achieve this instead of creating the `nodes` dictionary.

Comment: What is `res` exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right you want to convert a dictionary and put in a list

this dict: {"123":"Pass","987":"Fail","765":"Pass"}

to this list: [{Id:"123", value:"Pass"},{Id:"987", value:"Fail"}, {Id:"765", value:"Pass"}]

You could append it to a list:

```
dic = {"123":"Pass","987":"Fail","765":"Pass"}

my_list = []

def populateItems(response):
    for i in response:   
        id_val = {"Id": i, "value": response[i]}
        my_list.append(id_val)
        
populateItems(dic)        
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you're reading data out of it, it looks like the object that you're stating with, `response`, takes the form:

```
response = [
    { "key": "123", "Status": "Pass" },
    { "key": "987", "Status": "Fail" },
    { "key": "765", "Status": "Pass" },
]
```

Is that right?

And you want the final form to be:

```
result = [
    { "Id": "123", "Value": "Pass" },
    { "Id": "987", "Value": "Fail" },
    { "Id": "765", "Value": "Pass" },
]
```

You can convert it by using `map()` to convert each element in the list to a new thing. For example:

```
# This function converts the input dict format
# to the desired output dict format
def convert(dict):
    return {
        "Id": dict["key"],
        "Value": dict["Status"],
    }

def populateItems(response):
    return list(map(convert, response))
```

Then when you call `populateItems()` the result will look like this:

```
result = populateItems(response)
print(result)
=> [{'Id': '123', 'Value': 'Pass'}, {'Id': '987', 'Value': 'Fail'}, {'Id': '765', 'Value': 'Pass'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing responses to use an explicit for loop and using `map` are both great answers. For a third approach, consider using a list comprehension

```py
def populate_items(d: dict[str, str]) -> dict[str, str]:
    return [{"Id": id_, "Value": status} for id_, status in d.items()]

input_data = {"123": "Pass", "987": "Fail", "765": "Pass"}
assert populate_items(input_data) == [{"Id": "123", "Value": "Pass"},
    {"Id": "987", "Value": "Fail"},
    {"Id": "765", "Value": "Pass"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` to extract values from specified keys for each sub-dict, and reconstruct a new dict with values zipped with new keys:

```
from operator import itemgetter

response = [
    {"key": "123", "Status": "Pass"},
    {"key": "987", "Status": "Fail"},
    {"key": "765", "Status": "Pass"},
]

print([dict(zip(('Id', 'value'), itemgetter('key', 'Status')(r))) for r in response])
```

This outputs:

```
[{'Id': '123', 'value': 'Pass'}, {'Id': '987', 'value': 'Fail'}, {'Id': '765', 'value': 'Pass'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize list inside function, intialize dict inside loop, and append the dict to the list before returning the list:

```
def populateItems(response):
    nodes = list()
    for res in response:
        node = dict()
        node['Id'] = res['key']
        node['value'] = res['Status']
        nodes += [node]
    return nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_dict = {"123": "Pass", "987": "Fail", "765": "Pass"}

output_list = [{"Id": key, "value": value} for key, value in input_dict.items()]

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a comprehension with a dictionary constructor for each item:

```
response = {"123":"Pass","987":"Fail","765":"Pass"}

nodes    = [dict(Id=k,value=v) for k,v in response.items()]

print(nodes)
[{'Id': '123', 'value': 'Pass'}, 
 {'Id': '987', 'value': 'Fail'}, 
 {'Id': '765', 'value': 'Pass'}]
```